# Use TemplateRef Across MatTable ng-container(s)

Tags: angular

I am trying to reference an input inside a material table cell from within another cell.

```
<!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td class="expand" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <input
        #input   <--- the referenced element
        matInput
        type="text"
        name="name"
        [(ngModel)]="element.name"
      >
    </td>
  </ng-container>

<!-- Actions Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <a
        mat-button
        (click)="input.focus()"   <--- the reference to the element
      >
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

But I get error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'focus' of undefined`.
Is this possible at all? I'm using Angular 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query across an `ng-container` as the templateRef is out of scope of the other `ng-container` in the view... you will need to get the `elementRef` via `@ViewChild` and use a component method to set focus on the element.

```
 @ViewChild('input') _input;

 setFocus(){
    this._input.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

Then call `setFocus()` on click of your button

```
<!-- Name Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td class="expand" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <input
        #input   <--- the referenced element
        matInput
        type="text"
        name="name"
        [(ngModel)]="element.name"
      >
    </td>
  </ng-container>

<!-- Actions Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <a
        mat-button
        (click)="setFocus()"   <--- the reference to the element
      >
        <mat-icon>edit</mat-icon>
      </a>
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

---

If you need reference to each input from within each row, you will need to use `@ViewChildren` and pass the index of the row.

Setup action column and pass the index to the `focusInput(i)`

```
  <!-- Action Column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="action">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index"> 
      <button (click)="setFocus(i)">Focus Input</button>  
    </td>
  </ng-container>
```

Use `ViewChildren` to retrieve all inputs, use `i` to focus only the input in the row you are clicking.

```
@ViewChildren('inputs') _inputs
  setFocus(i){
    this._inputs.toArray()[i].nativeElement.focus()
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y49cpf-5rmklr?embed=1&file=app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: That was my original question - how to keep the reference in the scope of the MatTable row. While quite helpful, your solution is not accurate because it gets the reference to the input element on the first row only.

Comment: please see revision with stackblitz

Comment: That was almost exactly what I ended doing. My interpolation was using the #row and later `querySelectorAll()`. Your approach is really clearer than mine so I'm accepting it, with a minor change I got from elsewhere.